# R: Efficient way to modify elements from a data frame several times

Tags: r

I would like to perform several modifications to specific elements of a data frame without the code getting too redundant and messy.

For example, let's use the following data frame:

```
X <- data.frame(replicate(10, sample(-10:10, 10, rep=TRUE))) # 10x10 data frame
```

and perform these modifications:

```
X[X<3] <- X[X<3] * 10
X[X>5 & X<7] <- round(X[X>5 & X<7], 2)
X[X<0 & X>-10 & X!=-2] <- X[X<0 & X>-10 & X!=-2] * -1
X[(X>3 & X<10) | (X>-9 & X< -3)] <- X[(X>3 & X<10) | (X>-9 & X< -3)] - 1
diag(X) <- 0
X[upper.tri(X)] <- X[upper.tri(X)] + 0.5
and so on...
```

Is there a way to perform all these modifications (or at least some) using a more efficient/elegant code? maybe using pipes?

Comment: Why not a function?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns could you elaborate? or share an example? thank you

Comment: @mat, I'm confused.  There is no `R` function which will conduct each of these modifications with a single call, you're going to have manually code each modification.  There are ways to do this with pipes, but IMO they are no more efficient or elegant than what you already have. For example here is some `dplyr` code `X2 %>%mutate_each(funs(ifelse(. > 3, .*10, .)))` With this in mind, I might be missing something so please elaborate on what exactly you mean by "efficient".

Comment: It's not clear at all how these lines are at all related. I have no idea how you think this can be improved? I guess you are repeating the indexing twice. You could save that as a variable first to make it cleaner, maybe?